# How to get the path of all nodes in a hierarchy

Tags: javascript

I have a hierarchy of nodes in a checkbox tree and I would like to know how to make a recursive function that returns its complete path from each final element of a node, depending on whether it is selected or not.

Can someone help me?

For example:

```
A
 -A1
  -A1.1
  -A1.2
   -A1.2.1
   -A1.2.2
   -A1.2.3
 -A2
 -A3
 -A4
```

If **all** are selected, it should return next:

```
0: A/A1/A1.1
1: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.1
2: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.2
3: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.3
4: A/A2
5: A/A3
6: A/A4
```

If the item **A1.2.2** is not selected, it should return next:

```
0: A/A1/A1.1
1: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.1
2: A/A1/A1.2
3: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.3
4: A/A2
5: A/A3
6: A/A4
```

Data Example:

```
{
  id: 22,
  selected: true,
  children: [
    {
      id: 4813,
      children: [],
      selected: true,
    },
    {
      id: 4720,
      selected: true,
      children: [
        {
          id: 4838,
          selected: true,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: 4839,
          selected: true,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: 4840,
          selected: true,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: 4841,
          selected: true,
          children: [],
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4719,
      selected: true,
      children: [
        {
          id: 4272,
          selected: true,
          children: [
            {
              id: 4273,
              selected: true,
              children: [],
            },
            {
              id: 4275,
              selected: false,
              children: [],
            },
            {
              id: 4276,
              selected: true,
              children: [],
            },
            {
              id: 4277,
              selected: false,
              children: [],
            },
            {
              id: 4278,
              selected: true,
              children: [],
            },
            {
              id: 4279,
              selected: false,
              children: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I need a function that with data example return this:

```
response = [
    "22/4813",
    "22/4720/4838",
    "22/4720/4839",
    "22/4720/4840",
    "22/4720/4841",
    "22/4719/4272/4273",
    "22/4719/4272/4276",
    "22/4719/4272/4278"
];
```

Comment: Is there any attempt or extra info you can provide? such as how the checkbox state is stored and what gets passed into the function?

Comment: Of course, I edit the question

Answer (score 1):

The act of writing out the checkboxes recursively, and reading them recursively are pretty much a mirror image of one another.

Hopefully the below helps you along.

```js
var input={id:22,selected:!0,children:[{id:4813,children:[],selected:!0},{id:4720,selected:!0,children:[{id:4838,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4839,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4840,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4841,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4902,selected:!0,children:[]}]},{id:4719,selected:!0,children:[{id:4272,selected:!0,children:[{id:4273,selected:!0},{id:4275,selected:!1,children:[]},{id:4276,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4277,selected:!1,children:[]},{id:4278,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4279,selected:!1,children:[]}]}]}]};

function writeCheckboxes(input, elem, lvl) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.marginLeft = (lvl *10) + "px";
  var lbl = document.createElement("span");
  lbl.innerHTML = input.id;
  var cb = document.createElement("input");
  cb.type = "checkbox";
  cb.value = input.id;
  cb.checked = input.selected;
  div.append(cb);
  div.append(lbl);
  elem.append(div);  
  if(input.children) {
    for(var i=0;i<input.children.length;i++) {
      writeCheckboxes(input.children[i], div, lvl+1)
    }
  }
}

writeCheckboxes(input, document.querySelector("#checkboxes"),0);

function readCheckboxes(elem) {
  var cb = elem.querySelector("input")
  var res = {};
  res.id = cb.value
  res.selected = cb.checked
  res.children = [];
  var children = [...elem.querySelectorAll("div")];
  if(children.length) {
    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
      res.children.push(readCheckboxes(children[i]));
    }
  }
  return res;
}

document.querySelector("#getResult").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var top = document.querySelector("#checkboxes").querySelector("div");
  console.log(readCheckboxes(top));
});
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes">

</div>
<button id="getResult">Click me</button>
```

---

Based on the later edit of your question it seems you just want to turn the input into a specific output. That's easy enough to do recursively

```js
var input={id:22,selected:!0,children:[{id:4813,children:[],selected:!0},{id:4720,selected:!0,children:[{id:4838,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4839,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4840,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4841,selected:!0,children:[]}]},{id:4719,selected:!0,children:[{id:4272,selected:!0,children:[{id:4273,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4275,selected:!1,children:[]},{id:4276,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4277,selected:!1,children:[]},{id:4278,selected:!0,children:[]},{id:4279,selected:!1,children:[]}]}]}]};

function accumulate(input, curr) {  
  if(input.children && input.children.length) {
    var acc = []
    for(var i=0;i<input.children.length;i++) {
      if(input.children[i].selected)
        acc.push(...accumulate(input.children[i],curr.concat(input.id)))
    }
    return acc
  }
  else {
    return [curr.concat(input.id).join("/")]
  }
}

var result = accumulate(input, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that is not I need... I'm going to update the question